# Do problem weights change as the overall grade of an assignment is curved?

Tags: algebraic-curves, curves

When I get papers back for class, there's often a question or two that I know I could make a case for getting credit for my answer, but ultimately decide it's not worth the extra % in the grand scheme of the assignment. (e.g., on an 80 point midterm, I may not bother questioning why I got a 2 point question wrong).

My rationale is that the weight of this question is very small (2.5%), and not worth the effort really, when considering this actually translates to 2.5% of 40% of my final grade.

However, what if the whole class does poorly and the exam is curved heavily? At that point, does it make *more* sense for me to argue my 2 points? With the curve (assuming traditional curve), would it effectively make each question worth more at that point (since a curve could be seen as being given some points for free, per question)? So, would I actually be arguing for my 2 points *plus the extra points that on inherent in the curve for this question*?

This seems like the answer is "yes", but without some sort of formulaic proof, it's hard for me to convince myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.  It depends a bit on how the exam is rescaled.  Let's assume your teacher uses a very simple scaling by linearly taking the best score to $100\%$ and the worst score to $0\%$.  Let us also assume that you have gotten $70$ and everybody else in the class has gotten $71$.  This is clearly a terribly written test and an extreme example.  For now, you have $0\%$ on the exam as you have the worst grade.  If you get $2$ more points, you will have $100\%$ on this exam.

This is extreme, but the basic concept is that scaling that spreads the scores will make those $2$ points more valuable.  Scaling that just shifts the scores will not change the value of the $2$ points.  There may be scaling at the level of the total score, which again could make the points more valuable.